# Picking an IDE and language for Mobile Development

Tags: mobile, ide

I have been coding with xCode for a while now and have released two iOS apps. I have a good idea for my third app; however, I want it to be universal (accessible by all devices). What is a good IDE to use to code for all three major OSs (iOS, Android, Windows) at the same time?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not on topic on Stack Overflow. A Google search should get you a lot of good results though, especially if you specify which OS's you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the "Top 10" here... They aren't cheap.

http://thinkapps.com/blog/development/develop-for-ios-v-android-cross-platform-tools/